# semantics of target_link_libraries PRIVATE for a library target

Tags: cmake, build, linker, libraries, build-dependencies

In the [CMake documentation for target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html), it says:

> ```
> target_link_libraries(<target>
>                       <PRIVATE|PUBLIC|INTERFACE> <item>...
>                      [<PRIVATE|PUBLIC|INTERFACE> <item>...]...)
> ```
>
> The PUBLIC, PRIVATE and INTERFACE keywords can be used to specify both the link dependencies and the link interface in one command.
>
> Libraries and targets following `PUBLIC` are linked to, and are made
> part of the link interface. Libraries and targets following `PRIVATE`
> are linked to, but are not made part of the link interface. Libraries
> following `INTERFACE` are appended to the link interface and are not
> used for linking .

I don't quite understand how this applies to library targets.

Suppose my language is C or C++; that targets `lib1` and `lib2` are libraries, and that target `e1` is an executable. Now, if I write:

```
target_link_libraries(lib1 PRIVATE lib2)
target_link_libraries(e1 PRIVATE lib1)
```

Will `e1` necessarily be linked against `lib2` when I build `e1`?

Note: If the answer differs depending on whether `lib1`/`lib2` are static or dynamic libraries, please say so.

Comment: "... targets `lib1` and `lib2` are libraries (which themselves do not require linking, only compilation)" - Do you mean that `lib1` and `lib2` are **static** libraries? Because *shared* libraries definitely require linking.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Removed that piece of text. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

> Will e1 necessarily be linked against lib2 when I build e1?

Yes.

But `e1` will not have `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` nor `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` that are `PUBLIC` from `lib2`.

Comment: So, `PRIVATE` does not apply to linking, only to other properties of a target.

Comment: it doesn't apply to linking, in the sense that if lib1 depends _privately_ on lib2, the linking of e1 still knows about this dependence (and links against lib2), so it's not really a _private_ thing.

Comment: @einpoklum then in `cmake`, how can I hide `lib2` from `e1`? I think the whole purpose of `lib1` is to hide `lib2`

Comment: `how can I hide lib2 from e1?` If e1 is using symbols from lib2, one way or another it lib2 has to be visible from e1. You could make pack lib2 objects inside static library lib1, or you could make lib2 a shared library and link with it only on runtime. But one way or the other, it has to be there when executing.